# Python heroku sqlite3 existing table doesn't exist

Tags: python, heroku, flask, sqlite

I am attempting to move an SQLite database to Heroku using Flask so I can access it from a few devices. I am pushing the database to Heroku which I have created locally, so I know that the table exists.

**Client.py**

```
import requests, json
url = "https://someidijustmadeup.herokuapp.com/select"
j = {}
j["sql"] = "SELECT * FROM COMICS"
r = requests.get(url, json = j)
print("Status Code", r.status_code)
rJson = json.loads(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
print(len(rJson))
```

**Server.py**

```
import os

from flask import (Flask, jsonify, request)

from functions.functions import (executeSqlRequest)

host = "0.0.0.0"

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/select", methods = ["GET"])
def select():
    rJson = request.get_json()

    # Ignore the values, SELECT doesn't need them
    returnDict = executeSqlRequest(rJson.get("sql", None), None)

    return jsonify(returnDict)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host = host, port = port)
```

`executeSqlRequest` simply queries the database. The actual Flask application is fine, I can connect to it and run the queries.

**Info**

1. The DB file does exist and is being connected to, I have checked this.
2. I have run `cat database.db` remotely on the Heroku server and within the output I can see rows from the database so I know that the data is there. It also shows me the SQL for my table.

Comment: Heroku definitely doesn't support writes to SQLite (at least, not the way most users would expect). It _might_ support read-only SQLite (but it also might not—there's a good chance the library is just blacklisted). Are you intending to write to the database (from your application, from `sqlite3` on the command line, or _any_ way), or just read from it?

Comment: I intend to read and write to it from my application

Comment: That definitely won't work. I'll add an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku dynos have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make will be lost whenever the dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). Since SQLite is a file-based database it is incompatible with Heroku.

The good news is that Heroku has good support for client-server databases like PostgreSQL. In fact, it provides a [PostgreSQL database](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) by default. The `DATABASE_URL` environment variable will give you coordinates for connecting to that database.

If Postgres isn't your speed you can pick [another data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) from the list of addons.

Comment: That's very annoying. I have tried researching PostgreSQL before but i haven't found any good tutorial which a complete beginner in it can follow.

Comment: PostgreSQL really isn't all that different from SQLite as far as running queries goes. Yes, the setup is different. Maybe you should ask about the issues you're having with PostgreSQL? Heroku's decision not to provide a mutable filesystem is an interesting, defensible decision.